# Stack Overflowは初心者お断りなのか

Tags: 討議, 質問のクローズ

何を質問しているのか明かであり、明確な一つの回答を期待できる投稿があるとします。
通常、その投稿は閉じられたりはしないと思います。
しかし、あまりに初歩的であったり、質問者が初心者でプログラミング用語を使いこなせていない場合には閉じていく、という方向なのでしょうか。

だとしたら、トップページにでも「初心者お断り」と大書すべきだと思います。
初心者に無駄な挫折感を味合わせるべきではないです。

もちろん、「そんな初歩的な所から説明したくない」「突っ込み所が多すぎて疲れる」という気持は分かりますが、であれば読み飛ばせばよい事です。回答したい人が回答するのですから、放っておけばよい。その人が質問の編集もするかもしれません。

「一度閉じて、詳しい人が編集してくれるのを待つ」という運用方針もありえると思いますが、日本語版の現在の利用者数からすると、それでは再オープンまで時間がかかりすぎて、結局「初心者お断り」のサイトになります。

以上は、[MonacaでURLからデータを読み出す方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/18434/)の投稿を見て特に感じたことです。
この投稿は言葉の使い方に稚拙な所がありますが、回答は「XMLHttpRequestで取得した文字列をDOMに追加する」という一つの明確な物が考えられ、いきなりクローズするような物では無かったと思います。（現在は再オープンされたようです）

Comment: 初心者を受け入れるか、ということに関しては以下の討議も参考になるかもしれません： [～したいです。実装方法が分かりません。のような質問 - スタック・オーバーフローMeta](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2036/8000) / [該当分野では基礎的とされる質問への反応 - スタック・オーバーフローMeta](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1595/8000)

Answer (score 19):

本サイトはコミュニティ型ですので、どのような質問がクローズされるかはコミュニティが決める事になりますが、このサイトのトピックに沿っていない質問はクローズされやすい傾向にあります。（参考：[このサイトのトピックに沿う質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)）

ポイントは「質問者が初心者であるかどうか」ではなく、「質問がトピックに沿うかどうか」のため、特定の言語に関する初心者であっても、質問がトピックに沿っていればクローズはされないと思います。

なお、特定の投稿のクローズ判断が不適切という場合には、メタで個別に討議して頂ければと思います。

Comment: 質問や質問者のレベルは問わないという事ですね。回答ありがとうございました。

Comment: @mjy 「質問者のレベル」は問わないと思われます。経験豊富なプログラマーであっても「感想を求めているような質問」はクローズされる可能性があります。一方「質問のレベル」は問われると思います。レベルの定義が難しいですが「質問内容が不明確」の場合には、質問のレベルとしては低いと私は考えます。