# トラブルシューティングすれば解決する質問は質問するべきではない？

Tags: 討議

[こちらの質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/33692)で`このぐらいのトラブルシューティング～`というような
[初心者や勉学者を蔑ろにするような回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/33692#33704)を見かけました。
**※こちら修正済みです**

該当の質問が修正されておりますので、
認識違いということで経緯は修正履歴を見ていただければと思います。

---

基礎が出来ていないのに行うべきではない作業については質問をすべきではないのでしょうか？

例えば、初学者向けの作業ではない質問があるかと思います。
その場合など原因の切り分けが出来ないのであれば作業ないし、
上記のような質問するべきではないのでしょうか？

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

関連
[Stack Overflowは初心者お断りなのか](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2062/)

Comment: 私のした回答 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/33704/5793 のことを言われているのだと思いますが、「このぐらい」という言葉が誤解を招いているようですので回答を編集しました。

Comment: 討議されたいのが個別の投稿の是非なのであれば、どの投稿なのかを明記していただけますか？もしそれが上記の私の投稿なのであれば編集後の内容を質問に反映いていただけるとうれしいです。一般論なのであれば、個別の投稿を前提とした内容に寄りすぎているように思います。

Comment: そちらの質問ですね。認識違いのようですが、主題は変えないよう質問の方は修正しました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- 「質問」はしてもよいし、基本的には歓迎されるべきだと考えます。
- 「作業」に関しては本人が判断する事ですが、
  「（本番環境で作業しているなら）止めておいた方がよい」
  というのは常識的なアドバイスだと感じます。
  回答者がリテラルな技術面への回答だけでなく、質問者の状況や事情に対するアドバイスを行うのはありか、という所に議論の余地がありそうですが、このMeta質問の主題からは離れそうですね。

具体例として挙げられた投稿に関しては、「このぐらい」という文言の問題であったとすれば行き違いのようなものでしょうから、個別に議論する必要は無いと思います。