# 初心者への対応について

Tags: 討議

**1. 新行動規範での初心者への対応についての規定について**

(1) [新行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)では、初心者への対応については、次の規定があります

> 誰かを助けるためにここに来た場合には、辛抱強くなり、そして全ての人を温かく迎えるようにしましょう。 
>   新しいユーザーはスタック・オーバーフローのルールや仕組みをよく知らないかもしれません。サイトに慣れるまで、優しく辛抱強く見守ってあげましょう。

(2)容認できない行為があった場合は、通報の規定があります。

> 親切でお互いが尊敬されるコミュニティを構築するためには私たち一人一人の協力が必要です。もしも容認できない行為を見つけた場合、次のいずれかを行ってください。

> 有害な内容を通報してください。
>   内容にもよりますが、通報はモデレーターに注意を喚起し、時には自動削除をもたらすこともあります。

> ご連絡ください。 
>   できるかぎり早く回答いたします。

> すべての措置はモデレーションチームの裁量によりケースバイケースで行われます。モデレーターがどのように処理を行ったのか疑問がある場合は、直接ご連絡ください。

**2. 行動規範の変更に伴う対応について**

(1) 新行動規範の広報について

新しい行動規範が議論されていることは、メタでお知らせがありましたが、どのような変更があったのかは、殆どのユーザーは知らないと思います。新しく質問をしてくる人にもわかるように広報をすべきではないでしょうか。

(2) 「Stack Overflowは初心者お断りなのか」という質問への回答の修正について

[「Stack Overflowは初心者お断りなのか」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2062/) という質問には、23のプラス票が入っています。それに対する回答ですが、その当時としては問題はなかったと思いますが、新行動規範から見たときには、それでは十分でないと思います。みなさんはどう思いますか？また、回答に書いたようにそれを放置することは容認できないと思っています。それで通報しました。モデレーションチームからの回答もお願いします。

Comment: 具体的なご提案ありがとうございます！　(編集前の) 2の(2) については暫定モデレーターの権限を誤解なさっているように思います。モデレーターからの回答に強制力はありません。また、モデレーターがコミュニティの方針を決めているわけでもありません。モデレーター同士の意見が対立することすらあります。スタック・オーバーフローは皆さんのものです。メインサイトと同じく、メタサイトの回答が古くなっているのであれば、コメントで指摘したり、他の回答を投稿して vote を募ったりすることができます。モデレーターの役割について詳しくはヘルプページをご参照ください: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators

Comment: 「1.」については丸々(行動規範に関する文章からの)引用のようにも見えます。ご自身の発言と引用文とは区別が付く書き方をした方がよいのかなと思いました。 / 2.の(2)について、現時点での回答は今でも通用するものだと私個人は思いますが、もし改善案などがある場合には@nekketsuuu さんも書かれている通り**対案**を「他の回答」として投稿してみては如何でしょうか。

Comment: コメントでいろいろ言わずに回答をください。どうして対案を作らないといけないのでしょうか？質問に対してコメントをつけまくり対案のような過剰な要求をすることが、初心者には質問しづらい場所になっている理由の一つだと思います。

Comment: 規約はこうした議論の中では法律と同じで自由に使えます。著作権法第32条の引用ではありません。

Comment: 私個人としての回答は推敲中ですが、せっかく行動規範を話題にするのであれば、初心者への配慮だけでなくお互いの意見を尊重し合いましょう。 / **フィードバックをする時には明確で建設的に、そしてフィードバックを受ける時にはオープンマインドを心がけましょう。** - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: コメント欄で編集に関する議論が過熱していたように見えたため、その部分の会話をチャットに移動しました。質問の体裁に関わるお話は、必要であればこちらで続けて頂ければ幸いです： https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83977/discussion-on-question-by-yasuhiro-niji-

Answer (score 7):

※ これはモデレーターチームとしての回答ではなく、個人としての回答です。今回のご質問の趣旨とはやや外れた内容についての回答ですが、コメントにするには長いので回答として投稿します。

2.の(2) については、早過ぎた「通報」であった気がします。通報自体はありがたいですし、明らかにこのサイトに属しないと思うことがあった場合は通報機能を使うべきです。しかし今回のように投稿の文面ではなく投稿の趣旨自体の是非を問う場合、まずは元の回答へのコメント、新しい回答の投稿、あるいは今回のような問題提起の質問投稿で充分です。まずはコミュニティに意見を問い、それでも納得できなかった場合モデレーターをご利用ください。

モデレーターは単に[特権が無いと対処できないような事例を処理する役割](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)というだけであり、サイト方針を独断的に決めていくリーダーのような存在ではありません。その性質上たしかにメタへ色々投稿しているかもしれませんが、それはあくまでひとりのユーザーとしての行動です。モデレーターの投稿だからといって無批判に受け入れられるわけではありません。スタック・オーバーフローをどのようなサイトにするか決めているのはコミュニティ全体です。

このため、「この回答は古いと思うのでこのようにアップデートしたい」といった形式の質問には意味がある一方、「この回答は古いと思うのでモデレーターの誰かが更新してほしい」といった形式の依頼にはあまり意味がありません。モデレーターだからといって議論無しに誰かの回答の主旨を変えられるわけではないからです。

また、モデレーターだからといってメタにおける全ての議論へのメタ回答を強制されても困ってしまいます。モデレーターのマンパワーは限られていますし、「モデレーターの意見である」ということ自体はその意見の "良さ" にはあまり関与しないからです。(ただしもちろん、お困りの際にはじゃんじゃん通報してください :)

以上の理由から、今回の問題に関してもあくまでコミュニティから意見が集まり、コミュニティの投票によって意思決定がなされていくことを期待します。

Comment: コミュニティから意見が集まるのを待ちます。しかし、少数派は投票では負けますから「通報」するしかないわけで、そのことについては十分理解をしていただくようお願いします。

Answer (score 4):

> (2) 「Stack Overflowは初心者お断りなのか」という質問への回答の修正について

提案に概ね賛成です。
行動規範に沿った新しい回答があると良いと思いますし、自分でも書けるか考えてみます。
ただし、既存の回答はあくまで個人の意見だと考えた場合、回答を修正するのは（文字通りの意味とすると）避けるべきです。

#### 当該質問の質問者として、回答の承認に関して

当時はMetaサイトの性質や慣行を理解していない部分があり、早急に承認処理をしました。
今では、こういった「討議」に属する質問では一つの意見を承認する必要は無く、公平性を考えると仮に気に入った回答があっても承認はしない方が良いケースが多そうだと思っています。
当該の質問に関しても、承認された回答が有ることでこのサイトの公式の見解が示されているとの印象を与えると、それは事実と違いますので承認をはずしました。

Answer (score 1):

#### 行動規範の広報

ぜひ積極的にやるべきですが、「どのような変更があったか」は恐らくちゃんとしたドキュメントの形で残っていませんし(本家メタでのディスカッションがソースかと思います)、あったとしてもその"差分"を知らせる必要があるのかは疑問です。
行動規範の存在を知らせるだけで十分だと思います。

---

[行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)は**利用者全員**が守るべきルール・マナーであり、回答者だけが一方的に「初心者に親切にしましょう」ではありません。初心者かどうかに関わらず、質問する側も最低限守るべきルールがあります。

> **助けを求めてここに来た場合には、他の人があなたを手助けしやすいよう気を配りましょう。**
>   ガイドラインに従いましょう。そして私たちのコミュニティはボランティアによって可能となり存在していることを忘れないでおきましょう。

ある程度慣れの問題があるにせよ、質問者も自身の投稿を読む他人(ひと)に配慮して「親切に」振る舞う必要があります。

また、行動規範全体に目を通しても特にSOに特化した内容ではなく、普段の生活にも通用するようなごくごく当たり前のことを明言しているに過ぎません。行動規範のページを知っていようがいまいが守れない難しい内容ではないはずです。

---

#### 初心者とは？

「初心者」と一口に言っても色々な見方が出来ます。

- スタックオーバーフローを始めて利用する初心者
  SOならではの機能、「投稿時のMarkdown」「投票」「信用度」などシステム周りの仕様についての知識です。行動規範で「新しいユーザー」としているのもこの範囲に対してだと思います。

  > 新しいユーザーはスタック・オーバーフローのルールや仕組みをよく知らないかもしれません。サイトに慣れるまで、優しく辛抱強く見守ってあげましょう。
- 抱えている問題(例えばプログラム)の初心者
  プログラミングであるなら用語や記法を知っているか、などになると思います。
- 抱えている問題を他人に"言語化"して説明することの初心者
  判断が難しいのはこの範囲です。一つ前のプログラミングに関する知識が無いゆえにうまく説明できない場合もありますが、最低限「やりたいこと」「困ってること」辺りは説明できる必要があると思います。

teratail関連の記事でこの辺りに言及したものがありましたので紹介しておきます。

[新人プログラマよ，困ったときはこう聞け！～エンジニア特化型Q&Aサイト「teratail」のトップランカーたちが語る，確実な力を付けるための“質問力”](http://gihyo.jp/dev/column/01/prog/2016/teratail-q-force?page=3)

> 編集部：答えやすい，あるいは答えたくなるような質問はどのようなものなのでしょうか？ また，質問方法についてアドバイスがあればお願いします。
>
> argius：重要なのは質問のタイトルとタグですね。その2つで，質問の内容がだいたい見当がつきそうなものは答えやすい。とくにタイトルで要約を語ってくれる質問が一番いいですね。
>
> ryunix：あと，質問する前に，自分がどこまでわかっていて，どこからがわからないのかを整理して質問するのは重要かなって思います。そこを自分でもはっきりわかっていない状態で質問してしまうと，回答する側としても，どこから手を付けていいのかわからないので，結局，逆に回答が得られないことになってしまうと思うんです。まぁ多分そこが難しいところだとは思っているんですけど。
>
> argius：確かに（笑）⁠。整理とか説明する能力ってなかなか難しいですよね。でもやっぱり，技術的な能力はさておき，最低限の質問能力は鍛えてほしい。それは仕事にもつながることだと思うし，質問する人に頑張ってほしいところです。

#### 初心者はいつまで初心者？

SOに関する初心者という意味では「信用度」で判断する事も出来るでしょう。ただ、初めて質問する人でも勘どころが分かっていればキチンと説明出来ている人はいくらでもいますし、反対に登録から半年以上経ってもよほど自信が無いのか毎回質問に「初学者ですが」と前置きを入れる人も見かけます。

忘れてはいけないのは、**スタックオーバーフローはコミュニティでありサポートとセンターではありません。**
理想として「(初心者に)親切にしよう」と言っても限界があります。最低限のガイドラインに達していない質問まですべて懇切丁寧な対応を求められたらそれはもはやコンシェルジュです。回答やレビューをする人も役割が固定されているわけではなく、単なる一ユーザであることを忘れないでください。

---

#### 通報について

[Stack Overflowは初心者お断りなのか](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2063/3060)の回答は見直しの余地こそあるかもしれませんが、「通報」に至るような「迷惑行為」「偏見」「嫌がらせ」の言葉がありますか？
行動規範がどの程度の頻度で見直されるのか分かりませんが、見直しによって過去の発言が「容認できない行為として通報」される可能性があるなら、SO上での発言のリスクが高すぎます。

また、@Yasuhiro Niji さんのコメント「[投票では負けますから「通報」するしかない](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2793/%e5%88%9d%e5%bf%83%e8%80%85%e3%81%b8%e3%81%ae%e5%af%be%e5%bf%9c%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6#comment2451_2796)」はスタックオーバーフローのルールを無視した機能の濫用だと思います。これがまかり通ってしまうなら討議などせず、通した意見はすべて通報すればいいことになってしまいます。

---

#### 「閉じる/クローズ」について追記

引き合いに出されたメタ質問や、SO上でのやり取りでも勘違いをされている非常に方が多いですが、クローズ票はその場で質問を突き返す(=受け付けません)としているわけではありません。
オフトピックの場合を除いて、基本的には質問の不明瞭な点を明確にし、解決に導くための**ポジティブなフィードバック**と捉えるべきです。

とあるLinuxディストリビューションの行動規範によい言葉があったので参考までに引用しておきます。

> [Mageia プロジェクト - 行動規範](https://www.mageia.org/ja/about/code-of-conduct/)
>   何か衝突が起きた場合、あなたはまず、人々は善意をもって行動しているとみなすべきです。

とは言え「閉じる/クローズ」という単語からマイナスイメージを連想してしまうのも事実なので、この点については別のメタ質問で提案を行っています。

[「閉じる/クローズ」を別の言葉で言い換える](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2785/3060)

---

(以下余談)

teratailとの単純な質問数の比較だけでは「スタックオーバーフローが質問しづらい」とは断定できません。サイトの離脱率や利用をあきらめた人に理由をヒアリングする必要があるのではないでしょうか。

両者の何が違うのかを考えてみると

- スタックオーバーフローを英語のサイトと勘違いしている
  今でもたまに英語で質問をしてしまう人を見かけます。スタックオーバーフロー=Stackoverflow(英語)のサイトという勘違いから敷居の高さを感じている人もいるのではないでしょうか
- teratailでは「メタ(討議の場)」が無い
  討議の場が無いので仕方なく質問の形で投稿しているケースがあります。
  [最近のteratailについて](https://teratail.com/questions/29067)
- teratailでは恐らく「クローズ」が無い
  ただしSOと同じようなレビューシステムはあるので、「質問の丸投げに見える」「質問内容がはっきりしない」「タイトルが分かりづらい」「ここでの質問は不適切」などの評価が一つの質問に対していっぺんにされているケースも見かけます(初心者に対して親切でしょうか？)。

また、恐らく一連の議論の発端となった質問の一つ、「どのような多面体かを知るコード」は[teratailにもマルチポスト](https://teratail.com/questions/146328)されていますが、あちらでも一定数のユーザは「質問の丸投げ」と感じていたようです。見る人が変われば評価も変わるわけで、SOでのジャッジだけが特別厳しいものだったのでしょうか？

Comment: 余談の余談として、[スタックオーバーフローでは質問が自動削除されたりする](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2645/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%81%A7%E8%A7%A3%E6%B1%BA%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF-%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%82%92%E6%8A%95%E7%A8%BF%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BB%E3%81%97%E3%81%84)というのも、比較を難しくしている一因だよな、と思っています。

Comment: 投票は少ないですが的確なご意見だと思います。ただ一つ、英語で載せる人についてですが、私も載せようと思ったことがあります。英語圏の人たちが自分の質問を見て、英語で解答してくれてもいいなと思ったからです。検索人口が増える方が広く解答を得られるからです。私はたぶんこうなんじゃないかなと思っています。

Answer (score -2):

stackoverflow blog の記事 https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/「Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming.」にあるように、スタック・オーバーフローは初心者には質問しづらい場所だということは事実だと思います。それでは、いけないということで、新しい行動規範ができたと思います。

「Stack Overflowは初心者お断りなのか」の回答の趣旨は、「どのような質問がクローズされるかはコミュニティが決める」、「質問者のレベルは問わない」ということになると思います。それは、当時の規定としては当然の話なのですが、それでは初心者には質問しづらい場所だったので、新しい行動規範ができ初心者には、「サイトに慣れるまで、優しく辛抱強く見守ってあげましょう。」ということになったと思います。コミュニティは行動規範を守る必要があります。新しい行動規範ができた以上、それを回答に盛り込むべきだと思います。

特に、「なお、特定の投稿のクローズ判断が不適切という場合には、メタで個別に討議して頂ければと思います。」というだけではなく、「容認できない行為を見つけた場合は通報してください」という言葉を追加すべきと思います。

クローズされた事例があったので、メタに投稿してみましたが、初心者がメタの討議に参加するのは難しいのではないでしょうか。問題があった場合には行動規範による通報という手段が必要だと思うし、必要だからできたはずです。

このことから、「Stack Overflowは初心者お断りなのか」の回答を放置することは容認できないことだと思います。変わろうではありませんか？

**スタック・オーバーフローが質問しづらい場所だというデータ**

どうして10倍ぐらいteratailの方が質問数が多いのでしょうか？

teratailのトップ10のタグの質問数
PHP 20,010
JavaScript 16,076
Java 13,585
HTML 8,767
Python 7,619
Ruby 7,434
Swift 7,109
Ruby on Rails 7,075
WordPress 7,034
C# 6,948

スタック・オーバーフローのトップ10のタグの質問数
javascript 1,664
python 1,536
swift 1,290
ios 1,086
android 994
ruby-on-rails 978
php 975
java 902
ruby 775
C# 736

Comment: スタックオーバーフローは、一定の基準を満たした質問を自動削除する仕組みがあります。 [参考: コメントで解決した質問には、回答を投稿してほしい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2645/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%81%A7%E8%A7%A3%E6%B1%BA%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF-%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%82%92%E6%8A%95%E7%A8%BF%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BB%E3%81%97%E3%81%84)

ですので、単純な今現在の質問数の比較によって、「質問のしやすさ」が比較できるかというと、少し怪しいかもしれません。

Comment: 該当回答が「現在の行動規範に即したものではない」「追加的な補足が必要である」点には同意です。しかし、それに続く「回答を放置することは容認できない」には疑問があるのですが、容認できない＝(第三者意見であっても)削除/修正すべきであるという主張でしょうか？個人的に、該当回答に「容認できない」ほど現行規範と相反する主張が含まれているようには思えないのですが、どの点が容認できないでしょうか？

Answer (score -2):

(1) 新行動規範の広報について
広報はするべきだと思います。

初心者を受け入れるのは私たちの立場なので、コードオブコンダクトを熟知するのは、重点としては私たちの方だと思います。しかし、初心者も、やがてこのサイトに慣れれば、新しい初心者を受け入れる立場になりますから、いずれにしろ重要だと思います。

(2)「Stack Overflowは初心者お断りなのか」という質問への回答の修正について

> その当時としては問題はなかったと思いますが、新行動規範から見たときには、それでは十分でないと思います。みなさんはどう思いますか？

という部分について、どう問題がなく、十分ではないのかYasuhiroさんのお考えが少しわからなかったのですが、リンク先の解答を見るに、

> 本サイトはコミュニティ型ですので、どのような質問がクローズされるかはコミュニティが決める事になりますが、このサイトのトピックに沿っていない質問はクローズされやすい傾向にあります。

これが解答の核心だと思います。「初心者であるかどうか」ではなくて、「トピックに沿っているかどうか」で判断されることについて、十分ではないと考えられているということでしょう。

そして、そのトピックについてなのですが、

> •プログラミング上の具体的な問題、または
>   •アルゴリズムに関する問題、または
>   •プログラマーがよく使うソフトウェアに関する問題であり
>   •ソフトウェア開発に固有の、実際的で回答可能な問題である
>
> … ならば、この場で質問するのにふさわしいです！

とあります。

> しかし、あまりに初歩的であったり、質問者が初心者でプログラミング用語を使いこなせていない場合には閉じていく、という方向なのでしょうか。

「質問者がプログラミング用語を使いこなせていない場合には閉じていく」、のではなくて、「上のトピックに沿っているかどうかということだ」と解答されていたのですが、それでは、どう十分ではないのかがよくわからなかったです。

一応私の考え方としては、新行動規範を素直に読むと、

1.「辛抱強くなり」
2.「全ての人を」
3.「温かく迎える」
まず2から言います。すべての人をという事なので、ひょっとしたら初心者だけじゃないとも読めます。ただ、後の文で、「新しいユーザー」は、「スタック・オーバーフローのルールや仕組みをよく知らないかもしれません」とあり、そして、「サイトに慣れるまで、優しく辛抱強く見守ってあげましょう。」とありますし、新行動規範自体が、初心者を対象としていますから、「初心者すべて」と読んでいいでしょう。

「辛抱強くなる」はそのままでしょうか。ルールや仕組みに外れた行動をとると、つい何かを言ってしまいたくなりますが、そこはぐっとこらえて暴言等をはかない、ということですね。

最近私は「いつタグを追加するのか」、について、一悶着あったのですが、例えば、新しいタグを作るのかどうかは、私にとっては意識的には、初の試みであったと思います。権限が備われば作ってもいいと思っていましたし、英語版SOFにもあるタグでしたから追加してみたのですが、一旦編集削除をされたので、METAで質問をさせていただきました。また、「タグの乱立」についても、一言言われました。

しかし、「タグの乱立（特に、タグは何個くらいを目安とするべきなのか？タグを文章中に含ませることのできる記法はあるが、それを普段から利用してもよいのか、等）」と、「タグを作成する権限があり、かつ、英語版SOFでも存在しているタグを、まだそのようなタグが存在していない日本語版のSOFでは、いつ追加するべきなのか」という判断については、私にはわかりませんでした。

このように、「スタックオーバーフローのルールや仕組み」というものに、上記二つの事象が当たるのかどうかについても、私が決められることではないと思いますが、含まれるとします。

ただ、この二つについては、明確な規定と言うものがあるとは思えません。新たにMETAで話合うか、STACK　EXCHANGEという別の板を見て調べる必要があるようです。日本語版では、少な目に許容され、英語版では、もっと多めにという違いもあるかもしれません。

そうした仕組みやルールについての疑問を解消する手段を、早めに初心者に教えてあげるといいかなと思いました。
ただ、ほとんど英語で書かれているため、初心者の中にも、英語が不得手な方は多いかもしれません。基本は、METAであらかじめ同様の質問がないか調べていただき、存在しているかどうかを確認してもらい、なければ質問をしていただく、といういつもの流れでいいと思います。

更に言えば、初心者は、こうしたルールや仕組みを理解していないために、初めのうちは、私と同じような事件を起こしてしまうかもしれません。その時周りから見ている上級者の方たちがどう動くべきかという事は、日ごろから私たちが考えなくてはいけないことだなと思います。新行動規範は、こうしたところに焦点を当てているのだと思います。

私は、上に挙げたタグの、二つの件だけではない、さまざまな、「名前のないルールや仕組み」というものは、まだこのサイトに多く存在していると思います。できることなら、それらはすべてあらかじめ初心者に知らせておいてあげられるのが一番いいのだとは思いますが、現実的ではありません。

そのため、編集前の文章では、↑のような具体的事件をストックしていき、初心者が後で閲覧可能な形にしたり、質問内容に最低限の要素が加わるようにフォーマット化するべきだと言う意見を出してみました。例えば今でも、エラーコードだけを張り付けているだけの質問文があったり、逆に、エラーが出ているのに、エラーコードが全く見られない質問文がよく出ています。

私は、対象OSから～リンク先まで、そうしたことが起きないように、フォーマットを自分なりに考えて、試そうとしたのですが、あえなく撃沈しました。

こうした理由は、私の過去の質問`multiprocesssing`について尋ねたときに、Spyderというタグ、開発環境がないがために、皆さんに迷惑をかけたりしたり、言語のバージョンが抜けている質問文が目立ち、判断に迷ったことが自分でもあったため、ならば最初からこうしたものは定型文にしてしまえばどうかとおもっていたのでした。

これも今思えば、「名前のない仕組みやルール」のようなものかもしれません。そして、もしこの時に、新行動規範に沿っているかどうか怪しい対応を、上級者の方たちが見つけたら、通報や、
或いは、mjyさんの別質問新行動規範に沿っているかどうかを最終的に判断するのは誰か？という問題につながっていくのだろうと思います。

Comment: 何が言いたいんですか・・・？簡潔に書く練習をされた方が。

Comment: htbさんを精神分析すると面白いです。このコミュニティの中でhtbさんが一番わかりやすい。少なくともあなたが私にコメントをしてくることは、投稿したときからわかっていました。これは実際にコメントされてきたので予想通りです。なので「何が言いたいんですか・・・？」って実際はわかっているって思ってますｗで、そうであるとするならば、なぜこのようなコメントをしてきたのか・・・。まぁ、もうすべてわかってしまったので、これは私が勝手に考え、勝手に思い込んでいることだという事で、おしまいにしておきますね。

Comment: ちなみに上記コメントは私が編集をする前に行われたものです。

Comment: 長すぎてご主張が読み取れませんでした。当時。一年近く経とうとしていますが、簡潔になりますでしょうか